# Write/Read data to/from VRAM

Tags: graphics

My understanding of how a GPU works is kinda solid I think.

This is what I understood searching on the Internet:

VRAM (or framebuffer) stores what you see on screen.
Most of what the GPU does is encoding/decoding and processing data(mainly for 3D).
The GPU also sends (depending on the type of connection, HDMI, VGA etc..) data read from the framebuffer to the screen.

Anyway, I don't quite understand how this data is stored.

The GPU has serial ports which sends/receive data from CPU. But this is the part that I don't understand.
If the CPU sends only data(like images), how the GPU knows what addresses of VRAM will use for that piece of data if the CPU didn't send any address?

Old CPU architecture used 'inb' and 'outb' for reading and writing from and to an external device. Was it the same for GPUs?

Comment: your understanding is too far from full scene to fill all holes. today, cpu usually sends commands which is processed by GPU to make a picture. Since GPU is whole processor, the laguage of these commands may be arbitrary, you may look at OpenGL for one example

Comment: @Bulat So, the GPU has a cpu-like instruction set(?).

Comment: Yes, both are processors and differences between them are irrelevant to this question.

Comment: If you want to learn AMD GPU instruction set, look into https://developer.amd.com/wp-content/resources/Vega_Shader_ISA_28July2017.pdf